# How can I associate collections with different view layers?

Tags: viewlayers

Can I have collections separated into different view layers and combine them in the compositor? If so, how do you assign a collection to a view layer? I see the option to enable/disable a view layer for a collection, but the selection applies to all collections.

For example, I have BG, Mask and Objects collections and View layers BG, Mask and Objects. If I select the BG view layer and enable the view collection and disable the others, only the BG collection remains included.

If I select the Mask view layer, and do the same with only Mask being included, only Mask is included.

But then, if select the BG layer, the Mask collection is included, not the BG layer. How do I make BG include BG, Mask incude Mask and Objects include Objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be pretty straightforward.

I didn't understand the shortcut you used to disable collections from your question. This is how you exclude collections from view layers in the outliner :

[image]

Comment: Weird... I've spent a couple of hours following this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txUCkthVriw In the blend file I created, disabling a collection in one view, changes it for all the other views.  In that video render layers are added in composition as you go along. Maybe that's why. 

Anyway, recreating what you show there, the collection/view association sticks. Thanks!