# How to separate objects from lighting when compositing in 2.8+?

Tags: compositing-nodes, lighting, render-layers

I am familiar with the [Render Layers of 2.79](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/post_process/layers.html) and how to use one object to occlude another, and separate shadows etc from the objects that cast them. I would not call that old system intuitive, but I could use it.

I haven't done much compositing in recent versions of Blender and I don't know how Collections translate into layers for compositing. [The manual pages for the current 3.2](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.2/compositing/introduction.html#saving-your-composite-image) don't go into much detail when it comes to isolating lighting and object alpha and all that fun stuff.

[This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/220143/2952) was helpful for separating Render Layers, but their lighting isn't getting shared. Collections are totally disconnected from each other.

To be specific, I am using Cycles and have objects that emit. Theyr're on their own Render Layer. Then I have the environment that gets lit by these objects on a separate layer. I want the environment and the lighting *without* the objects that are the source of that lighting. I don't want those objects to be in the way when I separately make adjustments to the background of the image.

How is this kind of compositing done in recent versions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you've linked in your question shows how to activate or deactivate collections in certain view layers. If you have e.g. lights in a separate collection which is activated in all view layers, then the lighting is shared in all view/render layers.

But when you're using emissive objects and you just don't want to see them but still get the emission, why not simply deactivate *Visibility* > *Ray Visibility* > *Camera* on them? This way you have the light but the objects themselves are not shown in the image.

If you want to have different render layers, one with the object visible and one without, you can also duplicate a collection with *Duplicate Linked*. This way you can activate one collection for one view layer and the other collection for the other view layer. In one of them you can set the emission object to be visible for the camera, in the other it's invisible.